# How to trigger useEffect on initialization without changing the state in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I want to get a list of data and sort it when the page first loads, then I want to be able to sort by (fName) or (lName). The sorting works when I trigger the state change, but not on initial load, it displays in the order that the database gives it to me, I want to trigger the sort right after the data is loaded.

I have tried every solution I can think of without success.

the sortByfName() and sortBylName() is passed along as callbacks to the  to trigger from there.

*The sorting works backwards for some reason, that's why i pass along the opposite values, but that's another quirk that I will sort out later :-)*

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('lName');

  // GET DATA FROM SERVER
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/')
      .then((result) => {
        setContacts(result.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  // SORT CONTACTS
  useEffect(() => {
    const sorted = contacts.sort((a, b) => {
      let nameA = a[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      let nameB = b[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
      if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    setContacts(sorted);
  }, [sortBy, contacts]);

  const sortByfName = () => setSortBy('lName');

  const sortBylName = () => setSortBy('fName');

... A few more functions and then render the JSX
```

Comment: On first load which sort you want first `lName` or `fName`

Comment: fName I guess, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Then perform in your `.then` that sorting logic and set `setContacts` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, It would be better to pass a sort argument to API call, It's common and best-practice: `http://localhost:5000/?sort=fName`

But if it's not possible you must sort your data right after fetching the response.

```js
// GET DATA FROM SERVER
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/')
      .then((result) => {
        const sortedData = sortHandler(result.data, sortBy);
        setContacts(sortedData);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

And

```
const sortHandler = (data, sortBy) => {
   return data.sort((a, b) => {
      let nameA = a[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      let nameB = b[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
      if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
}
```

And further sorting on changing state

```
// SORT CONTACTS
  useEffect(() => {
    const sorted = sortHandler(contacts, sortBy);
    setContacts(sorted);
  }, [sortBy, contacts]);
```

Comment: I like best-practices, so thank you, that's the solution I'll go with! I'm new to this and really need to learn the common patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you perform the sorting logic before setting the `contacts` state on-component-mount. See my comment on the `.then` callback

```
// GET DATA FROM SERVER
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:5000/')
    .then((result) => {
      // perform sorting logic here before setting contacts

      setContacts(result.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

Other than that, I suppose you could refactor the API to sort according to X field before returning results

Comment: I tried to move the sorting to a function outside the useEffect and just trigger it from there and also before setContacts(), but I get: "The 'sort' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 47) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback."

Comment: you can use the `result` object - this is what you sort. also, I just realized you are directly mutating `contacts` state via the native [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function, i suggest you clone `contacts` first (e.g., via spread syntax) then sort that clone

Comment: I can see why it's bad to mutate contacts directly, but why via the spread syntax? Why not just copy contacts to a new object and do the operations on that?

Comment: Or wait, am I really mutating contacts? I thought I only read the values from contacts and stored them in sorted?

Comment: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) directly sorts & returns the array - it does not create a new array, like for example, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does

Comment: I tried the spread, but it creates an infinite loop, sigh..   
`useEffect(() => {const sorted = [...contacts].sort((a, b) => {`

Comment: this is because you set the contacts state inside useEffect via `setContacts(sorted)` - i.e., (1) set new contacts (2) use effect invoked (3) repeat step 1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your great solutions, but I ended up with another approach which seem better to me.

First of all I did the initial sorting in the database call. Best-practise :-)

Then it was just stupid to have the **sort** in a **useEffect**, since it is triggered by **event**, so I just made a normal function to pass along to the component with the buttons. I used the event to get the sortBy-parameter.

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  // GET DATA FROM SERVER
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/')
      .then((result) => {
        setContacts(result.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  // SORT CONTACTS
  const sort = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const sortBy = event.target.getAttribute('name');
    const sortContacts = [...contacts];
    sortContacts.sort((a, b) => {
      let nameA = a[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      let nameB = b[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
      if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    setContacts(sortContacts);
  };

// And so on
```